# How to do a Yup email validation on space separated values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have a string data e.g. `str="abc@gmail.com bcd@gmail.com"` I need to perform the yup validation on this string how can I do it.

I have found an answer for comma separated value here [github](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/564#issuecomment-580407848). I tried to tweak this answer by changing  `split(/[\s,]+/)` to `str.split("\\s+")` but It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the emails from the string with the following regex:

```
// this will split the emails regardless of how many white-spaces there are between emails
str.split(/[\s]+/);
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet to see the above regex split the white-space separated emails:

```js
// emails with random amount of white-spaces between them
const str="abc@gmail.com bcd@gmail.com   def@gmail.com       fgh@gmail.com";

str.split(/[\s]+/).map(e=> {
    console.log("Email: " + e);
})
```

---

However, if there is equal white-space between the emails in your string, you can just specify that in the `split()` method without using regex like this:

```
// change the number of spaces between the quotes according to the number of white-spaces between the emails in your string
str.split(' ');
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const str="abc@gmail.com    bcd@gmail.com    def@gmail.com    fgh@gmail.com";

str.split('    ').map(e=> {
    console.log("Email: " + e);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try  str.split(" ");